# Is there a telephone in Megan Reed's office?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

At the very beginning of the game, while browsing around Megan Reed's office, I kept on hearing a telephone ring. Since there's so many interactable things in there, I spent a while looking for it - after all, maybe I could answer her phone for her, since I was already checking her email and playing with her toy car.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find it. Is there actually a phone in there somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there is.  Interacting with each of the items in her office is part of an [achievement](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Old_School_Gamer):

> 1. The Ebook on the sofa to your immediate left.
> 2. A toy car on top of a filing unit in between a stack of papers and a printer (immediate right from where you start off).
> 3. A book on Megan's desk that reads "Being More Effective", it's about 3 feet to the left of the toy car.
> 4. Next is the emails on Megan's computer, you must scroll down each of them for it to count towards the achievement/trophy.
> 5. The picture is to the immediate left of the computer.
> 6. Lastly, the newspaper is at the end of the desk (on the left side).

Comment: Drat, I did get that achievement - I guess it's buried somewhere under the paperwork, if it's not her cell phone or something.

Comment: I think it's just part of the background noise track, I seem to remember other parts of other office environments having that sound in the background as well.